# Como puedo hacer que en este codigo al momento de soltar el clip automáticamente de clip a otro boton

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html>
<head><title> Ejemplo de los eventos onMouseDown y on MouseUp</title>
<script language=JavaScript>
function myButton_onmouseup() {
   document.form1.myButton.src = "img/arriba.png"
}

function myButton_onmousedown() {
   document.form1.myButton.src = "img/arriba1.png"
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<FORM NAME=form1>
   <img id="capa2"  NAME='myButton' class="img-circle" src="img/arriba.png" alt="Foto de AGUILA RUIZ"
   onmouseup="myButton_onmouseup()"
   onmousedown="myButton_onmousedown()">
</FORM>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola lo que tendrías que hacer es hacer simular el click, bien puedes hacerlo con jquery haciendo un trigger que es mas facil `$( "#foo" ).trigger( "click" );`  o en el otro caso tendrias que hacerlo asi con tu ejemplo.

```
<script>

    function myButton_onmouseup() {
        document.form1.myButton.src = "img/arriba.jpg";
        eventFire(document.getElementById('button'), 'click');
    }

    function myButton_onmousedown() {
        document.form1.myButton.src = "img/arriba1.jpg"
    }

    function clickear() {
        document.getElementById("texto").innerHTML = 'Texto cambiado por soltar click';
    }
    /**el => element , etype => event*/
    function eventFire(el, etype) {
            if (el.fireEvent) {
                (el.fireEvent('on' + etype));
            } else {
                var evObj = document.createEvent('Events');
                evObj.initEvent(etype, true, false);
                el.dispatchEvent(evObj);
            }
        }
</script>
```

```
<form name=form1>
    <img id="capa2" name='myButton' class="img-circle" src="img/arriba.jpg" alt="Foto de AGUILA RUIZ" onmouseup="myButton_onmouseup()"
     onmousedown="myButton_onmousedown()">
     <button name='button' id="button"onclick="clickear()">clickeame</button>
     <p id="texto">texto defecto</p>
</form>
```

Comment: Hola - no Funciono ya que tengo que dar clip  y soltar para q ejecute la primera accion  lo que queria era que al momento  de dar clip  sin soltar envié  el mensaje  y si lo suelto de clip al otro boton